# remove duplicate two criterion interval R

Tags: r, analytics, data-processing

I am working on cleaning and processing of data with R. I would like to remove the duplicates from a matrix. See the example below.
I would like to remove duplicate according to two criterion, and if it is possible using an interval (If the RT ± 0.1 and the m.z ± 0.001 for a same row is detected more than one time in the table, so remove the extra row).

```
        RT     m.z
1       2.02 326.1988
2       2.03 326.1989
3       2.06 326.1990
4       2.03 331.1533
5       2.03 375.1785
6       2.03 301.2852
7       2.04 301.2852
8       2.06 301.2852
9       2.07 357.2609
10      2.07 308.0327
11      2.08 218.2221
12      2.08 312.3617
13      2.10 473.3453
14      2.15 388.3929
```

I would like a out put like that:

```
        RT     m.z
1       2.02 326.1988
2       
3       2.06 326.1990
4       2.03 331.1533
5       2.03 375.1785
6       2.03 301.2852
7       
8       2.06 301.2852
9       2.07 357.2609
10      2.07 308.0327
11      2.08 218.2221
12      2.08 312.3617
13      2.10 473.3453
14      2.15 388.3929
```

If you can help that will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update it in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it with `dplyr`. Not sure if it's the most efficient way.

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("RT     m.z
1       2.02 326.1988
                                     2       2.03 326.1989
                                     3       2.06 326.1990
                                     4       2.03 331.1533
                                     5       2.03 375.1785
                                     6       2.03 301.2852
                                     7       2.04 301.2852
                                     8       2.06 301.2852
                                     9       2.07 357.2609
                                     10      2.07 308.0327
                                     11      2.08 218.2221
                                     12      2.08 312.3617
                                     13      2.10 473.3453
                                     14      2.15 388.3929"))
```

Now with the same data you provided.

```
library(dplyr)
# This calculates the difference in RT and m.z between consecutive rows
# and looks for absolute differences on which we filter further down the chain
df %>% mutate(
  rtdiff = abs(lag(RT) - RT),
  mzdiff = abs(lag(m.z) - m.z)
)  %>%
  # This replaces the NAs in the first row 
  #  with large values so filter does not have to deal with NAs
  mutate(rtdiff = replace(rtdiff, is.na(rtdiff), 999),
         mzdiff = replace(mzdiff, is.na(mzdiff), 999)) %>%
  # Remove the rows that don't meet your condition
  filter(!(rtdiff < 0.02 & mzdiff < 0.0002)) %>%
  # select only the columns you need and lose the rest
  select(RT, m.z)
```

giving us:

```
    RT      m.z
1  2.02 326.1988
2  2.06 326.1990
3  2.03 331.1533
4  2.03 375.1785
5  2.03 301.2852
6  2.06 301.2852
7  2.07 357.2609
8  2.07 308.0327
9  2.08 218.2221
10 2.08 312.3617
11 2.10 473.3453
12 2.15 388.3929
```

Comment: Ok so I think I have to sort the matrix for that. Indeed the table I gave you was just an example. I used to sort my matrix the followed function 
 `df=df[order(df$m.z),]`
Now I am tryin to use your code. I keep you informed.
Thank you !

Comment: If this answer worked for you, could you mark is as best answer and give it an upvote? thanks.

Comment: PS: You can also do the sorting in `dplyr` too with the arrange function.

Comment: Thank you very much this work very well. I gonna try to write the next step of the script. I gonna vote of course to thanks you for this fruitfully discussion.

Comment: I used the script after sort by RT and then by m.z. But it is still not enough I think I have to repeat the script at least 10 times to remove all the duplicates. Do you think is possible to make a loops for that ? Or they have an idea to make it but by screening for all the row instead of the followed one ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi It seems I have intercalated value between my replicates.

So I propose a small change in the Maiasaura code.

```
for (i in 1:100){
    reduced.list.pre.filtering = reduced.list.pre.filtering %>% mutate(
    rtdiff = abs(lag(RT..min.,i) - RT..min.),
    mzdiff = abs(lag(Max..m.z,i) - Max..m.z))  %>%


    mutate(rtdiff = replace(rtdiff, is.na(rtdiff), 999),
           mzdiff = replace(mzdiff, is.na(mzdiff), 999)) %>%

    filter(!(rtdiff < setRT & mzdiff < setmz )) %>%

select(RT..min., Max..m.z)}
```

Like that we check all the 100 followed values of a row. Hope it gonna helps somebody else. Do not hesitate if you have a better solution.